# How to SUM two values from two Different text box in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wanted to make a summation of two values from two different text boxes in a form so I had typed the codes correctly as shown:

```
Private Sub btnResult_Click()

Dim answer As Integer
answer = txtNum1 + txtNum2
txtAns.Value = answer

End Sub
```

That code should output in the box that named `txtAns` the sum of `txtNum1 + txtNum2` when I click on the button `btnResult`, But instead it output the two values next to each other without any calculation as shown in this picture:

[Click here to open the picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msiEE.png)

But, when I use another operator like ( / or * or - ) the calculation's output correctly!

So, What's going on?

Comment: Wild guess but I suspect it's treating the data as a string and concatenating, whereas the other operators assume integer.

Comment: Try `cdbl(txtnum1)+cdbl(txtnum2)` or `cint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example:

```
Dim answer As Integer
answer = "1" + "2"
Debug.Print answer
```

the integer value `12` is printed. What happens is that first the text expression `"1" + "2"` is evaluated, which yields the string `"12"`, which is the converted to integer value `12`.

If you would do instead:

```
answer = Int("1") + Int("2")
```

the value `3` will be printed.

In your script you can do:

```
answer = Int(txtNum1.Value) + Int(txtNum2.Value)
```

The `.Value` qualifier is probably not necessary as it is the default attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed solution, It works!